# WPF - xaml Scrollbar in a tab

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I wish to implement a scroll bar in a tab here is the following tab code i have:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="tabs"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="5 0">
        <TabControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, 
                                             Path=Value}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, 
                                             Path=Value}" />

        </TabControl.LayoutTransform>
    </TabControl>
```

However i know it is a scalable tab using a slider, but all i want is the scroll bar to display as another option instead of scaling the page all the time just for usability.

here is the code i have with the scroll bar implemented but it doesn't display.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabs"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="5 0"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TabControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, 
                                             Path=Value}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, 
                                             Path=Value}" />

        </TabControl.LayoutTransform>
    </TabControl>
```

im pretty sure by adding the code: ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" it should work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your described situation. For which element should be the property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility? As I know the TabControl will not consider this property. Or do you have a parent control which use this property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to wrap the `TabControl` in a `ScrollViewer` as `TabControl` does not have a `ScrollViewer` by default

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabs" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5 0" >
        <TabControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, Path=Value}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, Path=Value}" />
        </TabControl.LayoutTransform>
    </TabControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow thank you :) i creating the <ScrollViewer> in the <TabControl> at first lol :)